# How to match a pattern after particular string?

Tags: javascript, regex

*How to match some pattern using regular expression after* `SomeText`

Suppose I want to find email address, then I should get only:

`abcd@xy.com`
`cdf@errf.com`

But I should not get the emails written above `SomeText`, using regex in javascript.

I have a text file some thing like this:

> In theoretical computer science and formal language theory, a regular
>   expression (sometimes called a rational expression)[1][2] is a
>   sequence of characters that define a search pattern, mainly for use in
>   pattern matching with strings, or string matching, i.e. "find and
>   replace"-like operations. The concept arose in the 1950s, when the
>   American  abc@cd.com mathematician Stephen Kleene formalized the
>   description of a regular language, and came into common use with the
>   Unix text processing utilities ed, an editor, and grep, a filter.
>
> bfb@dgf.com
>
> SomeText
>
> name1/occupation1/state1
>
> abcd@xy.com
>
> Regexps are so useful in computing that the various systems to specify
>   regexps have evolved to provide both a basic and extended standard for
>   the grammar and syntax; modern regexps heavily augment the standard.
>   Regexp processors are found in several search engines, search and
>   replace dialogs of several word processors and text editors, and in
>   the command lines of text processing utilities, such as sed and AWK.
>
> name2/occupation2/state2
>
> cdf@errf.com

Comment: Hint: capturing group

Comment: but how to get all the results after SomeText? please explain

Comment: Use indexOf and substring (or split) to get the text after sometext,and then match what you need.

Comment: @Gopalkrishnasudhanshu -- you need to be more specific both about your problem (what makes "SomeText" special, while the following text "name1/occupation1..." is ignored) and about what you have already tried.

Comment: SomeText is a specific text  like a sub-header. and i have so many matching below and above some text. but i am interested in only the matching emails below SomeText.@Malvolio

Comment: 'SomeText' is uniuque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to get both email addresses after the "SomeText", so this is my suggestion.

Strip off all of the text before the key word. Then just use a simpler regex for email addresses. The regex below is the 'official' one from [emailregex](http://emailregex.com) but something like "([\w\d]+@\w+.\w+)" would work fairly well and is a little easier to understand :)

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("SomeText") + 1);
results = str.match(/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/mg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` with a callback:

```
var emails=[];

s.replace(/\bSomeText([\s\S]+)$/, function($0, $1) {
   $1.match(/[^\s@]+@\S+/g).map(function(e){ emails.push(e) });
   return $0;
})

console.log(emails);
// ["abcd@xy.com", "cdf@errf.com"]
```

PS: Regex to find email address `[^\s@]+@\S+` is pretty basic one here and email addresses can be pretty complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution:

```
var string   = '\nIn theoretical computer science and formal language theory, a regular expression (sometimes called a rational expression)[1][2] is a sequence of characters that define a search pattern, mainly for use in pattern matching with strings, or string matching, i.e. "find and replace"-like operations. The concept arose in the 1950s, when the American abc@cd.com mathematician Stephen Kleene formalized the description of a regular language, and came into common use with the Unix text processing utilities ed, an editor, and grep, a filter.\n\nbfb@dgf.com\n\nSomeText\n\nname1/occupation1/state1\n\nabcd@xy.com\n\nRegexps are so useful in computing that the various systems to specify regexps have evolved to provide both a basic and extended standard for the grammar and syntax; modern regexps heavily augment the standard. Regexp processors are found in several search engines, search and replace dialogs of several word processors and text editors, and in the command lines of text processing utilities, such as sed and AWK.\n\nname2/occupation2/state2\n\ncdf@errf.com';
var someText = 'SomeText';
var regExp   = new RegExp('\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+','g');
var emails   = string.split(someText)[1].match(regExp);
console.log(emails);
// ["abcd@xy.com", "cdf@errf.com"]
```

Don't forget to use your `RegExp` for searching emails. I've provided simplest example.

Comment: It's ~2 times faster then @anubhava solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
    var str='your text form which you need to find the email ids';

    str=str.replace(/\r\n/g,'##') // need to get all the text in one line otherwise your backrefernce will not work.

    str=str.replace(/.*sometext(.*)/i,"$1") // remove text before sometext

    str.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+/g)
```